# Проблема с открытием fancybox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Код html:

```
    <ul id="list">
        <li>list 1
            <ul>
                <li>sublist <a href="#settings" class="win">Окно1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>list 2
            <ul>
                <li>sublist <a href="#settings" class="win">Окно1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

<div id='settings' style='width:400px; display: none;' class='win-item'>
<h1 class="title">Окно1</h1>

</div>
```

Есть структура:

list 1

- sublist **Ссылка на fancybox**

list 2

- sublist **Ссылка на fancybox**

Делаю сворачивание:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#list > li').click(function (event) {
        $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Скрипт для fancybox:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    /* Apply fancybox to multiple items */

    $("a.win").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200,
        'overlayShow' : true,
        'overlayOpacity': 0.4,
        'overlayColor': '#000'
    });

});
```

Но когда нажимаю на ссылку окно не открывается, но сама ссылка срабатывает... Как я понимаю это конфликт событий. Как можно решить данное чудо?

Comment: Зачем вы два раза вызываете `fancybox` для одних и тех же элементов?

Comment: @korytoff Ну это как я понимаю не влияет на поставленный мною вопрос...

Comment: И привидите HTML свой

Comment: отлично, а где у вас ссылки в HTML на картинки?

Comment: @korytoff поправил вопрос

Comment: Смотри мой ответ, обновил

Answer (score 1):

### UPD

У вас в HTML нету ни слова про ссылки на картинки и селектор `"a.win"`.
И читайте [документацию](http://fancybox.net/howto) внимательнее, кусок кода который вы скопировали демонстрировал 3 варианта использования, а вы зачем то 2 варианта сразу юзаете.

Вот работающий код – http://jsfiddle.net/x6yxtpps/

В Ваш код нужно добавить ссылки:

**HTML**

```
    <ul id="list">
        <li>list 1
            <ul>
                <li>sublist <b><a href="https://thefancy-media-ec2.thefancy.com/images/common/fancybox_banner.png">Ссылка на fancybox</a></b></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>list 2
            <ul>
                <li>sublist <b>Тут нету ссылки!</b></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('#list > li').click(function (event) {
        $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
$("#list a").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200,
        'overlayShow' : true,
        'overlayOpacity': 0.4,
        'overlayColor': '#000'
    });
})
```

Comment: Это уже сделал, но проблема не в этом

Comment: @ArtemDoom проблема в том, что у вас не было ссылок `$("a.win")`, к чему вы хотели применить `fancybox` ?